# Bathroom Faucet arm extension isn't working

Tags: bathroom, faucet, pipe-fitting

I have a Delta Uxbridge faucet that tried to put a rotating arm extension on. However it still leaks with the rubber gasket and plumbing tape.

As a side note, I think I striped the plastic threads because the extension does not sit high enough to hold a metal cover on the faucet itself.

Would Delta carry metal versions of their plastic end fitting? Is there a metal fitting that I can buy and maybe make work? Is there a way I can make an adapter to go over the plastic threads and extension threads?

Faucet - https://www.homedepot.ca/product/delta-uxbridge-single-hole-single-handle-lever-bathroom-sink-faucet-standard-flow-deck-mount-in-chrome/1001779840

Arm extension I tried putting on - [https://www.amazon.com/1080%C2%B0-Swivel-Faucet-Extender-Universal-Sink-Water-Aerator/dp/B0B28TMGLG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B28TMGLG)

The arm extension works fine on another faucet I have.

Comment: Both links are invalid for me.

Comment: They work for me.

Comment: `However it still leaks` ... are you saying that it leaked before you installed the extension?